# Sample code of phoneGap which is been renamed as cordova

Tags: iphone, cordova

I want to have sample application on phoneGap for iphone.
i had done some research and found code from :-[here](https://github.com/filmaj/beerme)

But it had installed the phonegap which is now renamed as cordova.
So, in github it is showing error that no such file exist..
Please anyone help me

Comment: @Coder_sLAY NSEC_PER_MSEC not declared....IS it get any problem if comment that line??

Comment: http://prideparrot.com/blog/archive/2015/8/how_to_create_an_awesome_hybrid_mobile_app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The project which you are trying to open is very old which is made on lower version of phonegap.

What you can do is first of all install the latest one (Cordova-1.5.0)

Which is available here https://github.com/callback/phonegap

- Install the .dmg file from the iOS directory.
- Create a new Xcode project --- Select Cordova Based Application
- Copy the contents from www folder of beerme(which u wanted) and paste it in the newly created www folder(WHich may already contain cordova.js and an index.html file).

Run the application & Enjoy…

Here are some tutorials http://wiki.phonegap.com/w/page/35501397/Tutorials 
You can refer them

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has moved again. Why isn't there equivalent of a 301 redirect for old github accounts / projects?

https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios